# How to get listdir of a path with it path

Tags: python, directory, listdir

i want this

```py
>>> from os import listdir
>>> listdir(g:/new folder)
[g:/new folder/file 1, g:/new folder/file 2\]
```

but i'm getting this

```py
>>> from os import listdir
>>> listdir(g:/new folder)
[file 1, file 2\]
```

Comment: hey, listdir return names of entries of the input path, refer: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir, you might need to write extra code for modifying the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) function to get full path for each entry:

```
import  os

for f in os.scandir('your_path'):
    print(f.path)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import os

directory = "g:/new folder"
files = os.listdir(directory)
files_with_path = [directory+"/"+filename for filename in files]
```

It should do the trick given the doc, you could also look at the glob package
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir

https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: thank you but in my case i want to get all files in all folders of a directory so i can't use this.